# nginxで特定のサイトだけリクエストタイムアウトする

Tags: nginx

同一サーバー、同一IP上で2つのドメインを運用しています。ドメインはそれぞれwww.example.comとanother.example.comとしておきます。どちらのサイトもphp7.2で動いており、nginxでserver_nameによってアクセスを振り分けています。なので設定ファイルの違いはドキュメントルートだけです。

これで同時に運用しているのですが、another.example.comの方は正しく表示されるのに、www.example.comの方にアクセスすると「www.example.comからの応答時間が長すぎます」と表示されてアクセスできません。

色々調べましたが原因が皆目見当つきません。何をすればよいのか教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！nginxの `access.log` 、 `error.log` を貼り付けていただけますか？

Comment: nginx再起動時にドメインのIPを変えたのですが、どうやらそれの更新時間の問題だったみたいで、今は普通にアクセスできるようになりました！お騒がせしましたm(_ _)m